# Why won't the img show? what is wrong with "skrivut"

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = oppstart;

    var bokstaver = ["img/q.png", "img/w.png", "img/e.png", "img/r.jpg", "img/t.png", "img/y.png", "img/u.png", "img/i.png", "img/o.png", "img/p.png", "img/å.png", "img/a.png", "img/s.png", "img/d.jpg", "img/f.jpg", "img/g.png", "img/h.png",
        "img/j.png", "img/k.png", "img/l.png", "img/ø.png", "img/æ.png", "img/z.png", "img/x.png", "img/c.png", "img/v.png", "img/b.png", "img/n.png", "img/m.png"]

    var bokstav = ["q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p", "å", "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "ø", "æ", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m"]

    function oppstart() {
        document.getElementById("btnkonvert").onclick = klikket;
    }

    function klikket() {
        var input = txttekst.value.toLowerCase();
        input = input.split("");

        console.log(input);
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            for (var b = 0; b < bokstav.length; b++) {
                if (input[i] === bokstav[b]) {
                    document.getElementById("skrivut").innerHTMl += "<img src=" + bokstaver[b] + "  />";
                    console.log("<img src=" + bokstaver[b] + "  />");
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>`
```

What im trying to do here is making a kidnaplettergenerator. Its supposed to convert the text in input, to letters, that i've saved in my array, `bokstaver`.

The problem that i'm getting is that, the img wont show, help would be appriciated. :)

Comment: any error in the console?

Comment: No, it gets the letters, then converts to the img following the letter. But it wont show, quessing there is something wrong with my "skrivut"..

Comment: Begin by add simple quote aroung your `src`attribute : `src='"+code+"'`

Comment: can you share the output of console.log?

Comment: If you can share the source code i can check it.

Comment: @gurvinder372 not sure if this is the output but here it goes.

Comment: Check the DOM in the inspector. Do the images exist? Are the requests for the images successful (network tab)?

Comment: @gurvinder372 ["b", "r", "o", "r"]
oppgave6.html:28 <img src=img/b.png  />
oppgave6.html:28 <img src=img/r.jpg  />
oppgave6.html:28 <img src=img/o.png  />
oppgave6.html:28 <img src=img/r.jpg  />

Comment: @Victor have you add the simple quote ?

Comment: @Victor you need to add the quotes, also check the path of the images.

Comment: Here is the entire code :) http://pastebin.com/QqjiTWmN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("skrivut").innerHTMl
```

You need to write innerHTML, little typo there ;)

Comment: Thank you, seems like det gikk litt for i svingene ja :)

Answer (score -1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        for (var b = 0; b < bokstav.length; b++) {
            if (input[i] === bokstav[b]) {
                document.getElementById("skrivut").innerHTMl += "<img src=" + bokstaver[b] + "  />";
                console.log("<img src=" + bokstaver[b] + "  />");
                //add break
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Taking a break might help in some situations but what it is supposed to do in this situation to fix the missing images?

Comment: try to add alt attribute in img tag

Comment: May i know your input pattern